# Access violation writing location is occuring in Assembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, visual-c++

I'm programming in Assembly and the following error occurred to me:

> Exception thrown at 0x00B71792 in Application1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00B76BED.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x00B71792 in Application1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00B76BED.

I'm using Visual Studio to program. Here follows my code:

```
char *strCat(char *dest, char *src) {
    __asm {
        xor eax, eax
        mov ecx, 0xffffffff
        mov esi, src
        mov edi, dest
        mov al, 0
        cld
        repne scasb
        dec edi
    L0 :
        lodsb
        stosb
        test al, al
        jne L0
        mov eax, edi
    };
}
```

The error ocurr in `stosb` instruction according the debug.

In my point of view the code is correct. Couldn't find the error.

Comment: Have you stepped through the inline assembler in VIsual Studios's C++ debugger to watch what happens?

Comment: The value 0xffffffff looks suspicious.  What is it for?

Comment: We need to know what parameters you used to call that function.  You can't just go concatenating characters at will.  `strCat("abc", "123")` for example, will more than likely crash.

Comment: Assembly language without comments is useless.  I was told that rewriting assembly code that doesn't have comments is more productive than trying to understand it.

Comment: Aside: why `mov al, 0` having already done `xor eax, eax`?

Comment: Perhaps the damage occurs *after* the function returns since `mov eax, edi` will not return a pointer to the start of the destination string.

Comment: The problem is that the ECX register is used by the `repne` instruction.  Do you really need the `repne` prefix?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that is not the problem. `ecx` has been set up specifically because the `repne` uses it, and nothing else does.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes. @ThomasMatthews this value is for `repne` not exit with ECX and exit with ZF. @WeatherVane You are right, but this not influence in the code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm calling the fuction like this: `char *str3 = "aaaaa"; char *str4 = "bbbbb"; strCat(str4, str3);`

Comment: AFAIK `repne` is not useful for moving a string, but for comparing two strings, subject to the `ecx` count.

Comment: See @PaulMcKenzie's comment, above. You can't do that. Do you know C?

Comment: It does because you can't pass a string literal which is read only. Even if it were not, it still wouldn't have space to store the appended string. Note it doesn't work with the standard `strcat` either, it's not because of your assembly code.

Comment: @Jester How do you suggest I do `strcat` in assembly than?

Comment: `char str3[100] { "aaaaa" }; const char *str4 = "bbbbb"; //(will survive up to 99 bytes long result)` (plus fix the function arguments that `src` is `const char*`)  It's not problem with your assembly (maybe there some is, but the problem crashing your code is, that you are trying to write into read-only memory, which you didn't even allocate).

Comment: Also please note, how you managed to omit the important part of source in your original question. That's why [MCVE] is usually requested for debugging questions, because the people asking very often are looking for a bug somewhere else, where it really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the crash is that you're trying to concatenate characters onto a string-literal.  This is undefined behavior in C++ (and C).

To call your function safely, you have to

1) Ensure that your destination buffer is big enough to hold the concatenated string, and

2) The destination buffer is writable memory, not a string-literal.

To make the memory writable, one way is to simply declare a char array that is big enough to hold the entire concatenated string:

```
char destination[100] = "abc";
strCat(destination, "123");
```

Comment: Thanks man! It worked for me. The function is working as designed